# Xcode 6 not respecting autolayout constraints

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I had originally wanted my storyboard files to scale up to the size of the simulator/device screen. I was unable to figure out how to do this in Xcode 6.
My alternative idea, then, was to place constraints on the buttons within my project using interface builder. I placed some constraints on the buttons--for example, I attempted to place a centering constraint on one button by clicking on the background of the view and then connecting to the button (and then selecting "center horizantally in container"). But when I run my program, the button doesn't re-center. The same applies to constraints I place of trailing edges. XCode simply ignores all of them. If I run an iPhone 6 simulator, the buttons don't increase the space to fill the simulator (they "scale up" in the sense of size, but don't move themselves). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the constrains lines are blue (not orange and you have no warning saying that your button will show different at a running time. If you have any of these problems a good starting step is to delete the bad (oranges) constrains and use the "add missing constrains" re run the project and check the layout.

Another way is to delete all the constrains and use the "Add suggested constrains"  for one of your buttons and create the rest of the constrains based on that button.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made a link to an image of the problem. I am not sure if this is what you mean by "bad" constraints. Thank you. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l6A3xWa28m1iKFDXHWpdsCn8U5z7ljRKhFOYyDERaEc/edit

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. Delete that orange constrain and create a new constrain only to the top of the view and to your button on the left. that should work well. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Okay, so which option should I click to add that constraint ("top space to top layout guide")? (Just added an image to the top of the google doc)

Comment: ("top space to top layout guide") adn then add a spacing constrain to the back button.

Comment: ("top space to top layout guide") and then add another spacing constrain to the back button on the left. That will leave the choose button with two constrain and if the back button is well positioned it should be enough.

Comment: Okay, I added the first constraint. For the second one, which constraint should I add ("horizantal spacing")? Just doing that, without tweaking the second constraint doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Horizontal Spacing my friend. Then check that the constrains are in blue and you have no warnings.

Comment: Okay, have a look a the new image at the top of the Google Doc. Both contstraints are blue, yet as you can see in the simulator the button isn't centered. Thank you.

Comment: That is because it hasn't been initially centered when you dragged the button into the view controller. Did you use the blue guidelines? check that it is centered in the view controller. check that and if it is not centered delete those two constrains and re-add them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem of Xcode 6 It is that you are unable to become familiar with autolayout. If you want to place the button in center of the whole view then click on pin and click center vertically and center horizontally.[image]Then click on issues and click on height and width. Now your button will be in center of whole view and will have fixed width and height.If you have any problem regarding autolayout then you can comment with images.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Here is an example image of an unsuccessful attempt (it's in the next comment). Dragging and dropping an image into the comments section didn't seem to work.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l6A3xWa28m1iKFDXHWpdsCn8U5z7ljRKhFOYyDERaEc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No. I was under time pressure to create the file so I just disabled autolayout and rearraged things another way. Worked through the whole setting constraints and never could get it to work. Have a look at the google document if you want to see what we worked through, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: How big is the project if its just some small demo version then i can fixed the auto layout part and send you back

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is that you're not setting correct constraints.
As others pointed out :

- Make sure you've set the minimum number of constraints needed.
- if your element size is intrinsic - like a `UILabel` an `UIImageView` or a `UIButton` - you only need 2 other constraints (for X and Y position, as width and height are already given by the component `intrinsicContentSize` method).
- If you're forcing a size yourself, you need at least 4 constraints. (ex : top + bottom + left + right, or centerX + centerY + width + height)
- if you set constraints in storyboard, you should see warnings and errors (warnings when constraints don't relate to storyboard layout, and errors when the set of constraints cannot be resolved :you have not enough or too much constraints). Trust Storyboards warnings, there are here to help.
- If you create a 'center vertically' or 'center horizontally' constraint, make sure the constant is equal to zero. (in your screenshot, it was equal to 12)

You should list all the constraints you've set, and make sure they make sense together. Once you're comfortable with these, you'll see that XCode doesn't simply 'ignore' your constraints.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Warnings tell me the frame for the choose button will be different at runtime. Additionally, altering the constant as that was equal to 12 (making it zero) makes the contstraint orange, thus invalidating it.

Comment: No, 'orange' doesn't mean the constraint is 'invalidated', it only means that the Storyboard layout isn't in sync with the constraints. So this means that you cannot trust the XCode preview, as long as all these warnings are not solved. you have several ways to 'fix' this, `update frames` is usually the one I use once I've defined a set of constraints I'm confident with

Comment: Once you have no more warnings, you can directly update constraints constants, and the storyboard layout will be updated 'live'

Comment: The only warning I have is plain style unsupported in navigation item. And all the constraints are laid out for the choose button.

Comment: Then there is no more problem ? :)

Comment: Well it didn't ever work. I changed and will now construct the layout without autolayout. So technically speaking, there is no more problem, but I circumvented a potential problem with another weaker method, which is never a great idea.

Comment: oh... it's sad you didn't figure out how to use constraints :(